# Apollo 15 State Vector recreation

Tags: orbital-mechanics, apollo-program, simulation, apollo-15

I am trying to get the state vectors for Apollo 15 before, during, and after critical manoevers [sp]. IE TLI, LOI1, LOI2, lunar launch, preocking, postdocking, and TEI.

I am a totally newbie at all this. My experience comes from using the space flight simulator *Orbiter*.

My goal is to use the Apollo 15 Virtual AGC version of the spacecraft in the simulation to accurately portray the mission using the AGC computer and inputting the state vectors; any guidance on how to obtain these state vectors is appreciated.

Comment: Hi Tex, I made some small edits to your question and added some tags, have a look to double check and feel free to edit further. *Welcome to Space!*

Comment: Thanks. There is a document in the National Archives but finding it is like looking for The Ark of the Covenant. The Virtual AGC website has some documentation links I have gone through regarding the Archives. Unfortunately they need box and shelf information due to the quantity of material saved. The other Avenue is to generate the vectors from Adammo (sp) website about Reconstruction of Apollo 13 flight using existing NAT elements and converting to xyz elements,  earth or moon centered. It's a long road no matter the choice. The state victors were called up, radio transmitted.

Comment: Wow, it sounds like you've put quite a lot of work into this already! What are "existing NAT elements"?

Comment: Apollo form of orbital elements. I need to find a document for you to look at to get it. But suffice to say it's not simple x y z Vx Vy Vz. Has some ecliptic and other info.

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple ways to approach this question. You could take the trajectory parameters from this [postflight document](ftp://ftp.sciops.esa.int/pub/ekuulker/Apollo15_Navigation_Results.pdf). It doesn't have a full set of orbital parameters for all the cases you are looking for, but it is some actual tracking data which would have been uplinked to the AGC.

Then, as you are familiar with Orbiter, you probably know about the project I am working on. I am one of the developers of [NASSP](http://nassp.sourceforge.net/wiki/Main_Page), an addon for Orbiter that simulates the Apollo program and that has implemented the Virtual AGC. You can fly full missions with NASSP that are using the Virtual AGC. So that would give you several options, none of which will give you the exact trajectory or state vectors in the AGC from Apollo 15, but pretty close nevertheless:

- Fly Apollo 15 with NASSP yourself.
- Get someone (like me) to generate Virtual AGC core files (complete erasable memory dumps, not just the state vectors) for the specific points you want to have. These core files can be loaded in the standalone Virtual AGC application and will then give you the complete state of the AGC at the times you want. I have flown Apollo 15 in NASSP and so have some other people, so we wouldn't have to fly the whole mission again to do this, just load up some old save files and generate the core files.
- Get someone (like me) to do all of the things above, but just for the state vectors. State vectors alone won't get you all that far with the Virtual AGC though, there is a lot more to making it usable than that.

This goes a bit beyond a simple question/answer so you could make a post in our [forum](https://www.orbiter-forum.com/forumdisplay.php?f=102) to discuss more details of what you want to achieve.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XilioLHg1IJcrXymS9D-rbJ4P9PWd6mG) an example core file for the Virtual AGC, it's an Apollo 15 pre LOI file and has everything the CMC had loaded at that point. State vectors and many other things. This will be very close to the state of the CMC during the actual Apollo 15 mission.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't used NASSP Orbiter in a while. I was hoping  it was now at a point where the called up state vectors, Verb 71, could be keyed in and be put at that point in time at that xyz place. The simulator documentation gives this info, so I figured I could get A15 sim data and go from there.

Comment: The Virtual AGC is fully implemented in NASSP now, in both CSM and LM. Uplinks are generated mostly automatically, the state vectors are from the Orbiter API and are then converted to the right coordinate system for the AGC. This document describes the uplink format: https://www.ibiblio.org/apollo/Documents/HSI-208452.pdf

So would it be helpful for you if I gave you some state vectors in the V71 format? As I said before, the state vectors wouldl be close to the actual mission, but not exactly like it.

Comment: Thank you very much Indy91. To take time out of your life help me get to where i want to go is nice. Before you go through all that effort, i was going to get the A15 simulator package and other documents from the national archives in Ft. Worth TX. Im trying not to lean too hard on the NASSP team for info out of respect for their and your's time. One question I had was whether the Artemis is loaded with the preliminary PAD data. It must be important if they had it. And if you ran the standalone Virtual AGC in time sync with the Apollo NASSP side by side whether the same data comes out.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what document had you planned to request from NARA? "Apollo 15 Operational Trajectory Simulator Data Package (MSC memo 71-FM-141)" would probably be what you are looking for, that document is available for Apollo 10 online. Requesting these documents from NARA can be quite expensive though.

In the launch scenario for Apollo 15 in NASSP the padload is indeed loaded, if that is what you mean. And you can't run the standalone Virtual AGC with NASSP, only the build-in Virtual AGC version. I can send you a core file saved in NASSP for the standalone Virtual AGC.

Comment: I amended the original answer with an example core file for you to try with the standalone Virtual AGC. Very easy to generate for me, so if it works for you I can create more of them.

Comment: You're very astute. That was the exact doc I was going to request but am very concerned about the NARA charge for it. I have the Apollo 10 version. I'll post my wish list from NARA which would require an in person visit due to the cost. Plus I could digitally save them to USB.

Comment: I have a very long NARA wish list, mostly MSC memos just like that Apollo 15 document is. Ron Burkey, creator of the Virtual AGC, has been doing a lot of scanning at NARA of AGC documents and schematics and he kindly scanned a few from the top of my list as well, but so far that was just the tip of the iceberg. And I can't expect him to scan any more, after all it's for NASSP, a different project. I hope some day someone will do some scanning of documents specifically for NASSP. Anyway, have you been able to load the core file I provided in the original post?

Comment: Ill have to load up VirtualAGC. Ive been trying to save room on my drive for network engineering sims [gns3]. Please give me some time to get caught up. Also I think NARA has more docs on file then listed on that MSC doc listed what they gave them. Thus, someone in the NASSP fold will eventually need to go there.

Comment: Hi Indy91. I've got Virtual AGC up and running. Could you show me how to edit what file so I can incorporate yours? I figure it's one of the autobat ones; says "delete LM, delete CM". So do I remove one of these and enter yours? Thanks.  Tom

Comment: In the "VirtualAGC Simulation Manager" under Options, AGC Startup you can choose the option Custom. There you should be able to select any .core file to initialize the AGC erasable memory.

Comment: Thanks much for that info, and quick. I really do appreciate your help.

Comment: That file opens briefly and then shuts down abruptly, leaving me back at the start screen. Have you seen this issue before?  Thanks.

Comment: I've seen that before I think, when I hadn't set up the Virtual AGC properly. Does the same thing happen when you load it with a blank memory (AGC Startup option "Restart program, wiping memory")? If yes, then look at these instructions again: https://www.ibiblio.org/apollo/download.html#Installer_for_Windows Especially this line: "To run the program, create a simply create a desktop shortcut that executes the program ...\VirtualAGC\bin\VirtualAGC.exe from the working directory ...\VirtualAGC\Resources."

Comment: That is the issue exactly, except i dont know what that last instruction exactly wants me to do. The Virtualagc.exe is not in the Resources dir by default so i just copied it and moved it into that dir. It ran the default program fine. But when i loaded yours it wacked up the whole program after that. How do i point a shortcut to a dir if by default that program is not in that dir? Illogical. Ill try it and see, but....

Comment: When you have created the desktop shortcut right click to edit it. There you need to edit the "Start In:" line to have the Resource folder.

Comment: Its alive. Your core is up and running. Started Pre LOI keystrokes. Asking for GET. Shows 78 hrs 30 min 44.07 secs. Thanks for the help. Gotta prep for interview. More later.

Comment: I attemped to run a  P30 LOI burn [Program 30]. Virtual AGC took it fine but i ran out of info, ie Ground Elapsed Time, Vx Vy Vz for the burn, gimbal angles, etc. I have an Apollo 11 reference trajectory of the actual values i can use. But, i forgot inner, middle, outer gimbals relationship to roll, pitch, yaw, REFSSMAT. Need to look up. I do have an Apollo 11 Delco paperback book that can help but am trying to decide whether to auction it off or keep for reference. Torn equally.

Comment: The core file is from about 10 minutes before Apollo 15 LOI. P30 was already used before, but the Delta V values change when you run it again. In the simulation I would have used these P30 inputs: 078:30:44.07 GET and -2876.0, -640.2 and -127.5 ft/s. Was just an example file of course, there probably is not much to do with it in the standalone Virtual AGC.

Comment: I was wondering how to transfer the state vector of the CM to the LM after separation in Virtual AGC standalone and NASSP. I guess in VAGC one could output the SV, write it down, and then P71 it in, correct? How does it work in NASSP? Also, I am thinking more about that offer of yours to output key Core files. Should I make that request thru Orbiter forum?  Thanks Indy91.

Comment: Well there is a manual procedure to transfer a state vector between CMC and LGC, but that wouldn't normally be used. When the LGC gets activated it simply gets a state vector uplink from mission control. In NASSP it works the same, either an uplink with a special purpose MFD (the usual instrument for an interactive plugin in Orbiter) or via an automated mission control feature. You could make a forum post, or you could simply join us in our IRC channel, #nassp on freenode, and we can talk things over.

Comment: Hi Indy91. For that A15 core, what Orbiter and associated files did you install. Ive followed the instructions on the web site. Getting ready for a brand new install. I ran the core on VirtualAGC standalone but the V06 N43 didnt show the apogee or perigee changing. Correct? Thanks. T

Comment: Everything according to this guide: https://www.orbiter-forum.com/showthread.php?t=40351 And the standalone Virtual AGC doesn't simulate accelerometers, so apogee and perigee staying the same is normal.